# Like box stream needing refresh in IE before showing

Tags: internet-explorer, stream, facebook-likebox, muse

I have a like box in our car club website, it works perfectly in all other browsers I have tested with the exception of IE 9 (perhaps some older versions of IE as well).  The link to the page with this issue is: http://www.vettesofthesmokies.com/message-board.html

I used Adobe Muse to create the site, I can refresh the page and the stream will work.  All other parts of the like box works.  I have google groups HTML frame on the same page, but would not expect to be the issue.  I can refresh the frame in IE and get it to show the stream as well.

Comment: Well apparently all I have to do is post a question here and the issue resolved itself.  Scary...  I have had this issue for the past two weeks, have tried all sorts of things and just decided to post here for addional ideas, I noticed late yesterday after posting this that it was working properly now in IE.  I did nothing, didn't even upload any updates to the site, it just starting working.  I have checked it multiple times using multiple PCs running IE and it just works now.  Oh well!  :)